# Temporarily ignore click event in Meteor Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I want to temporarily ignore any click events on a button `#firstBtn` for 5 seconsd after it has been clicked on.

```
Template.sidebar.events({
    'click #firstBtn': function () {
        //...
    }
})
```

How can this be done? Looked into

```
$('#firstBtn').unbind('click', eventHandler)

Meteor.setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#firstBtn').bind('click', eventHandler) 
}, 5000)
```

but how should we refer to the click event handler in template `sidebar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**First, initialize a variable to set the timeout, and a variable to say if the button has been clicked. This is needed for the conditional statement.**

```
var timeout = 5000; //5000 milliseconds is equal to 5 seconds
var isClickable = true;
```

**Then, Try  some conditional testing like this:**

```
$('#firstBtn').click(function(){

if(isClickable){
...
//standard link handling code
...
isClickable = false;
setTimeout(function(){isClickable = true;},timeout)

}else{
return;
}

});
```

**This will only allow the click event's handling code to execute if the timeout is comeplete.**

---

## Good Luck!